# Grouping and aggregating with fields that don't need it

Tags: ms-access

I have the following data:

```
| ID |   Date   |  Code  |
--------------------------
| 1  | 26/02/14 |   10   |
| 1  | 25/02/14 |   11   |
| 1  | 24/02/14 |   10   |
| 2  | 25/02/14 |   13   |
| 2  | 24/02/14 |   11   |
| 2  | 23/02/14 |   10   |
```

All I want is to group by the ID field and return the maximum value from the date field (i.e. most recent). So the final result should look like this:

```
| ID |   Date   |  Code  |
--------------------------
| 1  | 26/02/14 |   10   |
| 2  | 25/02/14 |   13   |
```

It seems though that if I want the "Code" field showing in the same query I also have to group or aggregate it as well... which makes sense because there could potentially be more than one value left on that field after the others are grouped/aggregated (even though there won't be in this case).

I thought I could handle this problem by doing the GroupBy and Max in a subquery on just those fields and then do a join on that subquery to bring in the "Code" field I don't want grouped or aggregated:

```sql
SELECT Q.ID, Q.MaxOfDate, A.Code
FROM
    (SELECT B.ID, Max(B.Date) As MaxOfDate
    FROM myTable As B
    GROUP BY B.ID) As Q
LEFT JOIN myTable As A ON Q.ID = A.ID;
```

This isn't working though as it is still only giving me the original number of records I started with.

How do you do grouping and aggregation with fields you don't necessarily want grouped/aggregated?

Comment: Still too many records.. however I know what was wrong with my original subquery: I should `LEFT JOIN` on the date field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the CODE associated with the Max Date, you will have to use a subquery with a top 1, like this:

```
SELECT B.ID, Max(B.Date) As MaxOfDate,
 (select top 1 C.Code 
  from myTable As C
  where B.ID = C.ID 
  order by C.Date desc, C.Code) as Code    
FROM myTable As B
GROUP BY B.ID
```

Comment: I had tried the `FIRST` function, but unfortunately it does not reliably pick up the "Code" value I'm after. I need the "Code" value for the row found by the `MAX` of the date field.

Comment: Thanks - also just realised why my subquery wouldn't work.. needed to LEFT join on ID field AND the Date field. I'll accept your answer and add my own should others want an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer I accepted:

```sql
SELECT Q.ID, Q.MaxOfDate, A.Code
FROM
    (SELECT B.ID, Max(B.Date) As MaxOfDate
    FROM myTable As B
    GROUP BY B.ID) As Q
LEFT JOIN myTable As A ON (Q.ID = A.ID) AND (A.Date = Q.MaxOfDate);
```

Needed to do the `LEFT JOIN` on the Date field as well as the ID field.